# GridView Error Handling

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, error-handling, sql-server-2012

I'm creating a small web tool for some internal folks at my workplace.  This web tool accepts two input parameters which are sent through a stored proc on our SQL server.  The stored proc returns two tables into their own GridView in the web tool.

However, I'm noticing that if the stored procedure does not return any values for one or both of the results tables, the tool "blows up" and gives a runtime error.  If there are in fact no results in the table(s), I would love to have the GridView(?) state that there are no records returned.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString); 

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd; //Set up command variable
    cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[CSP]", con); //set command variable equal to CSP stored proc
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //set command type as stored procedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_number", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@part_number", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = TextBox2.Text;

    if (TextBox1.Text == "" && TextBox2.Text == "")
    {
        lblMessage1.Text = "Please enter the Account & Part Numbers.";
        lblMessage1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else if (TextBox1.Text == "" && TextBox2.Text != "")
    {
        lblMessage1.Text = "Please enter the Account Number.";
        lblMessage1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }

    else if (TextBox1.Text != "" && TextBox2.Text == "")
    {
        lblMessage1.Text = "Please enter the Part Number.";
        lblMessage1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }

    else
    {
        lblMessage1.Text = "";
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adp.Fill(ds1);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView2.DataSource = ds1.Tables[1];
        GridView2.DataBind();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me model how to approach this error-handling issue?  Hopefully this is clear enough.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

if (ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView2.DataSource = ds1.Tables[1];
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: thanks so much!  i knew it was simple but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Good catch, Kobe.  FYI - it's usually best to put some context / text explanation in your answers, rather than just writing code.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what your error is, so I can't speak to that.  But if you want to display some custom message when the GridView is empty, you can use the [GridView's EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    Move along, people - nothing to see here.  
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```